# ı cant find pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h library

Tags: include, point-cloud-library, vcpkg

I downloaded the PCL library from vcpkg. But I can't find this library pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h.
Then I executed this command. vcpkg install pcl[visualization] --triplet x64-windows --recurse. This is true ?.
But this has now taken up 15gb of space and is still happening. Is this what it should be?